# java.awt.Window.dispose() hangs forever in an Eclipse RCP project on Mac OSX

Tags: java, swing, awt, eclipse-rcp

Take the following:

```
public class MyTest {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
    new javax.swing.JDialog().dispose();
    }
}
```

Very simple, and as you'd expect it runs in only a couple of seconds, doesn't do anything & completes normally.

If you create a new Eclipse RCP project and add then run the main method in this class, the behaviour becomes unexpected.

On Windows, it runs fine.

On Mac OSX - it hangs forever on the `dispose`. I've tested this with OpenJDK 11 & 13.

I can only imagine there is some issue with the `classpath` of the RCP application...?

Comment: How is that an RCP? An Eclipse RCP doesn't use `main` or Swing.

Comment: It's not an RCP, your totally right.

I have an RCP application, where this is being used - although I think it's only being used to get dimensions on the display in my application

I thought I'd create the smallest possible example to illustrate the problem.

Comment: The code you show runs fine on my macOS system (10.15.4, Java 13.0.2). If your actual RCP is using SWT then mixing in Swing is not recommended and often causes problems. There are SWT APIs to get the display size.